# If an input is focused, then how to change the properties of a different class in the Sass?

Tags: html, css, syntax, sass, css-selectors

I try to change the color of one class at the same time when input is focused, but nothing changes

Code:

```
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="icon"></div>
  <input />
</div>
```

Sass selector:

```
.wrapper {
  input:focus & + .icon {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

Sass doesn't change anything, but clear css is working.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/Y83q6/2/

Does anyone know what should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 things:

1. Remove & from this par of code `input:focus & + .icon`;
2. Move `<div className="icon"></div>` under input. "+" it combines two sequences of simple selectors having the same parent and the second one must come IMMEDIATELY after the first.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it. Thanks!